# DropboxSDK: unable to link error

Tags: ios, swift, dropbox, dropbox-api

Following error in console:

> fatal error: DropboxSDK: unable to link; app isn't registered to query for URL scheme dbapi-2. Add a dbapi-2 entry to LSApplicationQueriesSchemes:

What am I missing? Help is very appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I got it fixed. actually LSApplicationQueriesSchemes takes an array of string. changing LSApplicationQueriesSchemes type from string to array fixes the above issue.